# Added a black background layer and now can't remember it, and want to remove it

Tags: 18.04

Thanks in advance.

There is a time I wanted to use netscape and since it did not give me the option to set the theme to black, searched through for something to make it dark.

Found out that there was something I could install, that doesn't not work for netscape specifically but for every application you install with a clear background.

Now I installed eclipse and with that 'something that I had installed', makes it look horrible and unusable.

I therefore want to get rid of it. But I don't remember what I installed to make this happen.

Anyone with any ideas on what I might have installed?

Comment: Do you mean theme? I'm sorry I don't really understand

Comment: By "clear" do you mean white? Currently, do **all** your applications have a dark background? Is your system an upgrade from an earlier version? If so, is the background issue a "hangover" from the earlier version? If you installed whatever it is during 18.04 itself, it maybe possible to help you. For starters, install *neofetch*, run `neofetch`, and post the screenshot here.